# adding reserved lot name in sale.order.line in odoov10

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

I would like to write small module that inherit `sale.order.line` and adding reserved lot on sale order line tree view.

under the sale.order.line module, there is the field name move_ids (stock.move , one2many) fields. I would like to create `move_ids.move_line_ids.lot_id`

So I tried the following code:

```
lot_name = fields.Char(related="move_ids.move_line_ids.lot_id", string="String")
```

but no luck and saw internal server error.

jooze

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, type of related field `lot_name` is [inconsistent](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/fields.py#L550) with `lot_id`.

Try to use a computed `Many2many` field to get all lot ids related to the current record.

***Edit:***

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    lot_ids = fields.Many2many('stock.production.lot', compute='_get_lot_ids')

    @api.one
    @api.depends('move_ids.move_line_ids.lot_id')
    def _get_lot_ids(self):
        # returns the union of all lots, with duplicates removed
        self.lot_ids = self.mapped('move_ids.move_line_ids.lot_id')
```

Comment: Hi can i get some sample for it? i am quite noob in odoo

Comment: hi there, there is an error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

Comment: I added the same example I tested to make sure it is working. Please add the complete error message and update your question with the code you used in case it is different.

Comment: sure now working.  I saw "lot" column in list view of Sale Order line but "no records"  showing in value.

Comment: This is because the lot is not defined for all movement lines

Comment: Does this answer help you?